# Can we use async/await with RxJS Pattern?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, reactive-programming, ngrx

I have the following scenario.

If the users enter in the route with only `/lobby` without an `?competitionId=` I must search on the state the favorite competition of the user. After receive the favorite competition of the user, i must redirect the user to `/lobby?competitionId=XYZ`.

I'm using the following code. Is a better way to implement ? It's looking like an callback hell to me. I'm using NGRX.

**RxJS Stream Observsable Way**

```
redirectToCompetition(): void {
this._store.pipe(select(routerSelectors.getState)).subscribe(routerState => {
  if (!routerState.queryParams.competitionId) {
    this._store
      .pipe(select(authenticatedUserSelectors.getFavoriteCompetition))
      .subscribe(favoriteCompetition => {
        this._store.dispatch(
          new routerActions.NavigateTo({
            path: ['/lobby'],
            query: { competitionId: favoriteCompetition.id }
          })
        );
      });
  }
});
}
```

I rewrite the code using async/await. It looks better.

**Promise Async/Await Way**

```
async redirectToCompetitionPromise() {
    const routerState = await this._store
      .pipe(select(routerSelectors.getState))
      .first()
      .toPromise();

    const userFavoriteCompetition = await this._store
      .pipe(select(authenticatedUserSelectors.getFavoriteCompetition))
      .first()
      .toPromise();

    if (!routerState.queryParams.competitionId) {
      this._store.dispatch(
        new routerActions.NavigateTo({
          path: ['/lobby'],
          query: { competitionId: userFavoriteCompetition.id }
        })
      );
    }
  }
```

Any problem to use RxJS with async/await pattern ? Or in my first code i'm doing an bad implementation ?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with use async/await and promise with rxjs, just rxjs itself can handle it quite well already, if use right

```js
this._store
.pipe(select(routerSelectors.getState))
.first()
.filter(routerState =>routerState.queryParams.competitionId)
.switchMap(()=>this._store.pipe(select(authenticatedUserSelectors.getFavoriteCompetition)))
.do(favoriteCompetition =>
        this._store.dispatch(
          new routerActions.NavigateTo({
            path: ['/lobby'],
            query: { 
            competitionId: favoriteCompetition.id }
          })
        );
      ).subscribe()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We can't put `first()`, `filter()`, `switchMap()` inside de `pipe( ... )` ?

Comment: just my personal perference, don't like pipe too much myself. I don't see it save a lot of typing

Comment: Great. Just one thing is wrong is your implementation based in my use case. I edited your answer to fix to mark your answer as the correct. Thanks!